# NSTextView non-editable in NSSplitview

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nssplitview

I have an NSSplitView in My window. the left is an NSOutlineView. When I click the OutlineView's item, the right Which is a custom ViewController's view  will look like the below：

Screenshot:

[image]

then，a problem occurs that the two NSTextView can't editable while editing the textview. however，I have make it possible to edit it.

Screenshot:

[image]

Am I missing anything?
Any hint in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Thanks

This is my demo code:github.com/ljz2012008/TestN.git

Comment: How are you populating the contents of the `NSTextView`?

Comment: Why did you switch Field Editor on? Switch it off.

Comment: The two NSTextViews are normal NSTextViews that are dragged from the object library.

Comment: I tried to turn it off. Still can not edit

Comment: How are you populating the contents of the `NSTextView`?

Comment: This is my demo code:https://github.com/ljz2012008/TestN.git

Comment: I think NSSplitViewController isn't designed to be used without a storyboard.